# Esconder elemento após o mesmo ser carregado na página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho na minha página o seguinte script do google:

```
<body>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript>
  <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-abcdef"
          height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden">
  </iframe>
</noscript>
<script>
  (function(w,d,s,l,i){
    w[l]=w[l]||[];
    w[l].push({
      'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
      event:'gtm.js'
    });
    var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    var j=d.createElement(s);
    var dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
    j.async=true;
    j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);                    
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-abcdef');
</script>
...
```

Que, ao renderizar a página, insere as seguintes tags `<img>` no final do meu `<body>`

```
  <img width="0" height="0" src="https://ib.adnxs.com/getuid?https://rxs.roixdelivery.com/delivery/counter?c=1255&amp;CHN=WEB&amp;apid=$UID&amp;rnd=939508138223">
  <img src="//p.rfihub.com/cm?in=1&amp;pub=3657&amp;btag=2&amp;csurl=http%3A%2F%2Fs.thebrighttag.com%2Fcs%3Ftp%3Dqw8KooS" width="1" height="1" border="0">
</body>
```

Estas duas imagens criam um espaço em branco no final da minha página, e eu precisava inserir `display: none;` nas mesmas para ocultar este espaço. Porém, tenho alguns problemas:

1 - As imagens são carregadas dinamicamente pelo script, portanto não tenho controle nenhum sobre elas e não consigo colocar nenhuma classe para ocultá-las.

2 - Os seletores: `$("body img:last").css("display","none");` e
    `$("body img:last").prev("img").css("display","none");` funcionariam para capturá-las e aplicar o estilo, porém elas são carregadas após os eventos `$(document).ready()` e `$(window).load()` e portanto os seletores não funcionam.

3 - Não pretendo usar nada como setInterval, pois caso estas imagens não tenham sido carregadas ainda após o período que eu especificar, outras imagens serão ocultadas erroneamente. Porém, tenho certeza de que estas são as ultimas imagens a serem carregadas no `<body>`

Como posso contornar esta situação?

Comment: E se você fizer assim? $("body img:last").on('load', function() { console.log("image loaded correctly"); })
    .on('error', function() { console.log("error loading image"); })
    .attr("src", $(originalImage).attr("src"))
;

Comment: Já tentou `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn());` ?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa seu script não funcionou na minha página :/

Comment: @devgaspa continuo com o mesmo problema. As imagens são carregadas após a execução desse script.

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos e se você fizer um callback para está função ?

Comment: @devgaspa, você diz para a função que adiciona as imagens? Se sim, não tenho como acessá-la, o script do Google faz isso internamente.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver!

Não tinha parado pra pensar que adicionando um css `display: none` com os seletores `body > img:last-child` e `body > img:nth-last-child(2)` faria com que somente essas imagens fossem aplicadas à regra.

Obrigado à todos pela ajuda!